# How to configure spring boot to throw 404 error if route does not exist?

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, http-status-code-404

So I have a bunch of nested routes in a controller. I want to make sure that the application throws an error if the particular nested route does not exist. Right now, if the nested level if more than 2, the application returns `null` instead of throwing an error saying route cannot be found.

**Example:**

```java
@RestController 
@RequestMapping(value="v1/")
public class EmployeeController {

    @Autowired
    EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;


    // Get Token Info
    @RequestMapping(value = "read/tokenInfo", method =  RequestMethod.GET)
    public Token getTokenInfo(@AuthenticationPrincipal Token token) {
        return token;
    }


    // List of all employees.
    @GetMapping(path = "read/list")
    public List<Employee> getAllEmployees() {
        return employeeRepository.findAll();
    }
```

In the above code,  say for the route  **`v1/read/tokenInfo`** has 3 segments to it - v1, read and tokenInfo. If I were to mistype the route and try something like - **`v1/read/tokeninfosss`** instead of showing an error, it returns 200OK with **`null`** message.

**response:**
[image: response]

However, if there were only 2 levels to the route - as follows -

```java
@RestController 
@RequestMapping(value="v1/")
public class EmployeeController {

    @Autowired
    EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

    // Get Token Info
    @RequestMapping(value = "tokenInfo", method =  RequestMethod.GET)
    public Token getTokenInfo(@AuthenticationPrincipal Token token) {
        return token;
    }
```

And now if I call - **`v1/tokenInfosss`**, it will throw an error -
**404 error:**
[image: 404 error]

I have also configured security as follows -

```java
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()    
        .antMatchers("/local/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/v1/read/**").hasAuthority("Display")
        .antMatchers("/v1/modify/**").hasAuthority("Update")
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .oauth2ResourceServer()
        .jwt()
        .jwtAuthenticationConverter(getJwtAuthenticationConverter());
}
```

Any idea how to configure this 404 error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try end ur path with / and remove / from v1
`@RequestMapping(value="v1")`

and

`@RequestMapping(value="/read/tokenInfo/", method =  RequestMethod.GET)`

Comment: The path with pathvariable in them do not work ex - /v1/{id}

Comment: i test ur code with simple spring boot and every thing is ok. maby another controller match to this path

Comment: Yes you are right. Other controllers were getting matched cos I had a controller with signature -> v1/{id} where id was of type String. This was getting triggered whenever I called other endpoints like v1/list or v1/count . It had nothing to do with trailing/leading slashes. Still thanks

Answer (score 1):

Spring will do this automatically. If you do not have proper request mapping annotation, spring will return with 404. The problem is that in your request mapping. When you give `@RequestMapping(value = "read/tokenInfo", method =  RequestMethod.GET)` like that, it will accept any request such as `read/tokenInfossesf` because of your path.

> By default, Spring MVC performs .* suffix pattern matching so that a controller mapped to /person is also implicitly mapped to /person.*.

Please, check also [spring documentation for request mapping annotation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping)